# Phonegap Blackberry build error for cross domain

Tags: blackberry, cordova

When i build my application from phonegap. It works in iPhone, iPad, Android but didn't work in blackberry.

I'm calling cross domain API WSDL.

In blackberry it gives error

```
 URL (exmple :- http://google.com)- could not be retrieved because it was not found in config.xml.

 Please verify the <access> elements in the WebWorks config. Contact your service provider if the problem persists.
```

I have to use in `config.xml`

```xml
<access subdomains="true" uri="*" /> OR <access origin="*" />
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Last time I had this issue it seems all URL's have to be explicit for BB. If your URL is unknown at runtime (For instance, a user entered URL), The only way around it would be

```
<feature id="blackberry.app" >
    <param name="websecurity" value="disable" />
```